# Create copies of rasters in R via GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, r

I am looking for an efficient way to create copies of
rasters in R via GDAL. Since the advantages of such an
approach might not be directly obvious, here is some more
context.

Via GDAL we can read from very different sources and also
write to various destinations. E.g. a raster source might
life in a ZIP file on an HTTPS server and one wants to
create a copy in a S3 bucket that requires authentication.

Since GDAL provides direct support for such use cases (e.g.
via [network based file systems](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#network-based-file-systems))
I would like to omit additional dependencies in my package's code.
However, the approaches I tried so far seem not to scale very well,
say to hundred of files.

My issues with the approaches I tried so far are:

- download.files: very fast, but would require additional
  dependencies/code to read/write from/to cloud buckets, also
  might not be applicable to all types of raster sources
  (say WMS) and it creates an explicit temporary copy
- terra: works actually very good and keeps the metadata and compression,
  but it takes relatively long time and does not scale well
- sf::gdal_utils: great if I want to change e.g. the file
  format (say GTiff to COG), but does not create an exact
  copy without specifying the right creation options, also
  it does not scale well
- gdalmanage: creates an exact copy, seems like the fastest
  way if I want to go through GDAL, but I did not find
  any R bindings for the utility and I'd like not to rely
  on system calls in package code

Does anyone know of either an R binding to gdalmanage or
another more scalable approach to create copies of rasters
via GDAL?

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.8.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.72

src <- "https://storage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC-2022-v1.10/Hansen_GFC-2022-v1.10_gain_40N_080W.tif"
dst <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif")

# simple download, but cannot target single files in e.g. zips
# or sources that require authentication / opening options etc.
system.time({
  download.file(src, dst)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.071   0.038   1.791

# read and write with terra
system.time({
  r <- rast(src, vsi = T)
  writeRaster(r, dst, overwrite = TRUE)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  11.503   6.334  24.470

src <- paste0("/vsicurl/", src)
# powerful, but does not create an exact copy (e.g. w compression)
system.time({
  sf::gdal_utils("translate", src, dst)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   2.723   0.569  36.088

# seems like an exact copy, but no R binding available?
system.time({
  cmd <- sprintf("gdalmanage copy %s %s", src, dst)
  system(cmd)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.702   1.514  13.430
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should be roughly equivalent to gdalmanage, and would work for the general case of a GDAL dataset which could be multi-file. It calls GDALCopyDatasetFiles(). GDAL needs to open the dataset to obtain the file list so it takes longer than download.files.

```
library(gdalraster)
src <- "https://storage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC-2022-v1.10/Hansen_GFC-2022-v1.10_gain_40N_080W.tif"
src <- paste0("/vsicurl/", src)
dst <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif")

copyDatasetFiles(dst, src)

ds <- new(GDALRaster, dst)
ds$info()
ds$close()
```

The development version of [gdalraster on GitHub](https://github.com/USDAForestService/gdalraster) also has vsi_copy_file(), an R wrapper for [VSICopyFile()](https://gdal.org/api/cpl.html#_CPPv411VSICopyFilePKcPKcP8VSILFILE12vsi_l_offsetPPCKc16GDALProgressFuncPv) supporting GDAL Virtual File Systems.